# Can we build ionic mobile app with grabbing details from wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, ionic-framework

Can we build ionic mobile app with grabbing details such as products, videos .. from wordpress site

Comment: can you explain it please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can use [Wordpress API v2](http://v2.wp-api.org/) to enable APIs for your website.
2. You can create a native or hybrid mobile app to call these REST APIs and grab it's contents.

For your question in one of the comment, the source database is the same for both your website and mobile app. If you add a new post,video or photo it can be accessed from your mobile app if you use the APIs correctly.

If your mobile app uploads data using API, the same would be available in your website.

Comment: Thank You Purus for your quick reply. i will search and do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can write or use a Wordpress API plugin that provides content from your Wordpress database. For example use this plugin in your Wordpress webite:
https://nl.wordpress.org/plugins/json-api/

Comment: lets think i want to add videos , products so on .. to both wordpress website and ionic mobile app at once through admin panel.so how can i do that? I'm new comer to this .please can you explain it to me?